# Is there a function that waits for a button to be clicked instead of using the event function

Tags: c#, forms, button

In Windows forms, is there a function that waits for a button to be clicked instead of using the event function?

Basically I want to continue a piece of code in a function after the enter button has been clicked instead of taking me back to the start of the click event function. Or is there another way to tackle this?

Okay sorry, EDIT: I haven't written any code for the story yet, I have just my base classes and such, however think of it more like an interactive story, It has a linear style of game play that follows a story, I will have different functions that control different parts of the story, However what i want is every time the enter button is clicked is to continue from where the story left of last. Thanks for input

Comment: After the code has run in the click event, call the second function?

Comment: No because there will be allot of button clicking as it is a text based game

Comment: You could use a `Mutex` to wait for a signal that you send from the buttons click event code.

Comment: @juharr Mutex fine if executing code and button click happening on differnt threads - if not fine just to use a flag

Comment: I guess that you have a load of code in the click event? If so, you probably want to move all that code into a separate method and read a bit about event driven programming

Comment: @Ricibob If the function is running in the same thread (I'm assuming the UI thread here) then it would block the ability to click on the button in the first place.

Comment: @juharr I think the real issue is the OP has not really provided enough info about what hes doing - in the executing code or the button handler.

Comment: You need to create a [State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). (I am leaving this as a comment instead of an answer as I do not have enough time to write a complete answer up, but hopefully someone will see this and will post an answer explaining how to do it in more depth)

Answer (score 0):

i would build a class called `GameState`.

this state would keep up with the items to be displayed on a single screen. Graphics, text, title, etc.

then i would find a way to sequence multiple instances of that GameState object, a simple option would be a `List<GameState>` that is read in from a textfile/database/config at startup.

each time the user presses the button, move some global counter forward by one increment, and refresh the game state to the screen.

this way the button "does the same thing" every time, because what it does is stored in a separate class.

This separation of UI and data will simplify many more things as you proceed.